# Execution Context not getting shutdown

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am running into a strange problem where the execution context is not getting shut down.I tried with or without await.

```
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

  val customExecutor: ExecutorService =
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(serviceConfig.serviceConf.numberOfThreads)
  implicit val customExecutionContext: ExecutionContext =
    ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(
      Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)
    )

    futureCall() map { result =>
      import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

      customExecutor.shutdown()

      customExecutor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)  
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are waiting for the shutdown inside a thread, but the executor can't shut down while a thread is running so it's not going the happen. So move the `awaitTermination` outside the `map` function.

However the real problem is that you are creating two `ExecutorService`s and stopping the wrong one. If you just pass the service that you created, it terminates as expected:

```
val customExecutor: ExecutorService =
  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)

implicit val customExecutionContext: ExecutionContext =
  ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(customExecutor)

futureCall() map { result =>
  customExecutor.shutdown()
} 

customExecutor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Comment: I tried this as well:    futureCall() map { result =>
    } onComplete { _ =>
      import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

      customExecutor.shutdown()
      customExecutor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }

Comment: I've updated the answer with what I think is the actual problem, let me know if it works for you.